# iPad Dataformatter error

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have written the code to add imageview in `UIview`(TestView).and in the touches delegate method for adding images i tap anywhere in the view then the images is add in the `UIview`(testview) and also this image is add into a mutable array which is declared in appdelegate class.
and another array contains the frame of that images.
 above process is done for every tap to add image.
and in deleting process we delete the images and related index of mutable array.
we can also move the any images to anywhere in the view.

but the build is working very slow and crased on the ipad device and shows following  error :-

> ```
> Program received signal:  “0”.
> Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib")
> ```

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    CGPoint point_Temp = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:TestView];
    point_TouchStart   = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:TestView];
    bool_ValidtouchFound = NO;

    for(int int_Temp=0; int_Temp < [appDelegate_iPad.marry_ContainsRect count]; int_Temp+=1)
    {
        NSValue *val_Temp = [appDelegate_iPad.marry_ContainsRect objectAtIndex:int_Temp];
        CGRect rect_Temp = [val_Temp CGRectValue];
        NSLog(@"rect_Temp = %f, %f",rect_Temp.origin.x,rect_Temp.origin.y); 

        if(CGRectContainsPoint(rect_Temp, point_Temp))
        {
            bool_ValidtouchFound = YES;
            int_TextIndex = int_Temp;
            imgview_Temp = [appDelegate_iPad.marry_ContainsImages objectAtIndex:int_TextIndex];
            for(UIImageView *imgview_Transparent in [imgview_Temp subviews])
                imgview_Dummy = imgview_Transparent;
            [imgview_Dummy setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, imgview_Temp.frame.size.width, imgview_Temp.frame.size.height)];
            [imgview_Dummy setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [imgview_Temp addSubview:imgview_Dummy];


            if([appDelegate_iPad.marry_ContainsImages count] > int_Temp)
                imgview_Text = [appDelegate_iPad.marry_ContainsImages objectAtIndex:int_Temp];
            break;
        }
    }           
}

 - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{   
if(bool_IsTextReadyToMove 
   && ![appDelegate_iPad.CurrentFeatureStatus isEqualToString:@"Pencil"] 
   && ![appDelegate_iPad.CurrentFeatureStatus isEqualToString:@"Eraser"]
   && ![appDelegate_iPad.CurrentFeatureStatus isEqualToString:@"Brush"])
{
    float float_difx = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:imgview_Text].x - [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:imgview_Text].x;       
    float float_dify = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:imgview_Text].y - [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:imgview_Text].y;   
    CGAffineTransform transform_NewTemp = CGAffineTransformTranslate(imgview_Text.transform, float_difx, float_dify); 
    imgview_Text.transform = transform_NewTemp;     
}
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
if(bool_ValidtouchFound)        
{
if(appDelegate_iPad.bool_IsTextReadyToDraw)// code to draw images
        {
            UIImage *img_Temp = [UIImage imageNamed:appDelegate_iPad.str_ImageName];
            UIImageView *imgview_DrawText = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:img_Temp ];

            CGRect rect_Temp = CGRectMake(point_Temp.x, point_Temp.y, img_Temp.size.width, img_Temp.size.height);
            [imgview_DrawText setFrame:rect_Temp];
            [imgview_DrawText setTag:101];

            UIImageView *imgview_SubView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, img_Temp.size.width, img_Temp.size.height)];
            [imgview_SubView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [imgview_DrawText addSubview:imgview_SubView];

//          [imgview_SubView sendSubviewToBack:imgview_DrawText];
//          [imgview_DrawText bringSubviewToFront:imgview_SubView];
//          imgview_DrawText.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
//          imgview_DrawText.layer.borderWidth =0.6f;


            [appDelegate_iPad.marry_ContainsRect addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect_Temp]];
            [appDelegate_iPad.marry_ContainsImages addObject:imgview_DrawText];
            [TestView addSubview:imgview_DrawText];

            if(imgview_DrawText)
            {
                [imgview_DrawText release];
                    imgview_DrawText = nil;
            }
            if(imgview_SubView)
            {
                [imgview_SubView release];
                imgview_SubView = nil;
            }
            if(img_Temp)
                img_Temp = nil;

            NSLog(@"Array Count After Addition = %d",[appDelegate_iPad.marry_ContainsRect count]);
        }
        else // Code for Delete images
        {
            for(int int_Temp=0; int_Temp < [appDelegate_iPad.marry_ContainsRect count]; int_Temp+=1)
            {
                NSValue *val_Temp = [appDelegate_iPad.marry_ContainsRect objectAtIndex:int_Temp];
                CGRect rect_Temp = [val_Temp CGRectValue];
                if(CGRectContainsPoint(rect_Temp, point_Temp))
                {
                    UIImageView *imgview_RemoveText = [appDelegate_iPad.marry_ContainsImages objectAtIndex:int_Temp];
                    [imgview_RemoveText removeFromSuperview];
                        imgview_RemoveText = nil;

                    [appDelegate_iPad.marry_ContainsRect removeObjectAtIndex:int_Temp];
                    [appDelegate_iPad.marry_ContainsImages removeObjectAtIndex:int_Temp];
                    break;
                }
            }
            NSLog(@"Array Count After Deletion = %d",[appDelegate_iPad.marry_ContainsRect count]);
        }
      }
}
```

So, Please Provide me help.
Thanks

Comment: You might want to add information about the error you are getting.